# How to disable accessibility voiceover on NSTableView for Mac OS using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility, nstableview, nstablecellview

Tried the following so far and it doesn't work:

```
cellView?.setAccessibilityElement(false)
cellView?.setAccessibilityEnabled(false)
```

Both the above are getting called within `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set `accessibilityElement` as `false` for all subviews in TableViewCell, not only cell itself. (label, button..)